# Data aggregate in r

Tags: r

I have a data set (test)

```
v1 v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
1   1   1   0   0   0 
2   2   1   1   0   0 
3   2   1   0   0   0 
4   3   1   0   0   0 
5   3   1   1   0   1 
6   3   1   0   1   1 

structure(list(V1 = 1:6, V2 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V3 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), V5 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

and I want to achieve this

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
 1   1   1   0   0   0  
 5   2   2   1   0   0  
15   3   3   1   1   2
```

I have tried this:

```
aggregate(test[c('v3', 'v4', 'v5','v6')], list('v2'), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

which is not working. I want to aggregate the data in (test) based on V2 and sum the other variables.

Comment: More importantly, it is completely unclear how you want to get from the input to the output. What is the relationship between them?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: I can guess at what you mean to do, but simply providing input and output is woefully inadequate. Be nice to the people trying to help you and include an explanation _in English_ of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I guess he wants to `aggregate` by `v2`, and `sum` all the rest of the columns. I'm sure this question has been asked before.

Comment: @nograpes, that’s the question, thanks. Indeed there are several questions about the ‘aggregate’ command, I could not solve my problem with the offered solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `aggregate` command to:

```
aggregate(. ~ V2, test, sum)
#   V2 V1 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1  1  1  1  0  0  0
# 2  2  5  2  1  0  0
# 3  3 15  3  1  1  2
```

Some things to note:

1. R is case sensitive. The sample data you provided has variables named with upper-case "V"s, but the sample code you've tried has lower-case "v"s.
2. You're trying to refer to the variable names directly. For that, you either need to be using the formula notation for `aggregate()` or you need to be using `with()` or (not recommended) `attach()`.

Comment: nice use of aggregate with formula.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial attempt was almost correct. With minor correction you can achieve what you want. This assumes you want to aggregate-sum rows by V2

```
result <- aggregate(test[,c('V1', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5','V6')], list(test[,'V2']), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)

> names(result) <- gsub("Group.1", "V2", names(result))
> result
  V2 V1 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  1  1  0  0  0
2  2  5  2  1  0  0
3  3 15  3  1  1  2
```

Comment: If you don’t mind I will go with the solution of Ananda Mahto, but thank you for your solution, I’m learning a lot of it, and positive feedback.